# Get average of multiple rows with criteria and return those rows

Tags: mysql

I'm attempting to get any items that are the same type, but are ranked one higher that have an average equal or greater than the item ranked below.

I have a table and query like http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e14ca/4/0 although instead of returning 'd' and 'e' separately, I would like them first to be averaged (50+65)/2 = 57.5 and then check if they are greater than or equal to 'a' * 10 (50). If that is the case, return 'a', and 'd' & 'e'.

My expected output per the example is

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
| title | type | rank | price | title | type | rank | price |
|-------|------|------|-------|-------|------|------|-------|
| a     | 2    | 2    | 5     | d     | 2    | 3    | 50    |
|       |      |      |       |-------|------|------|-------|
|       |      |      |       | e     | 2    | 3    | 65    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add your expected output?

Comment: @oNare I've edited in to the question my expected output.

Comment: By expected output he means the desired results.

Comment: @Mihai That is my desired result. Sorry if I'm not understanding you correctly.